# Strange behavior of matplotlib when overlaping two plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

First I have these data and the plot is OK

```
dic={'x': {0: '1', 1: '3', 2: '4', 3: '7', 4: '9', 5: '10', 6: '11', 7: '13', 8: '14', 9: '16'},
    'y': {0: '0', 1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '1', 4: '0', 5: '1', 6: '1', 7: '1', 8: '1', 9: '1'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

plt.scatter(df["x"],df["y"])
```

[image]

Then I have these data and the plot is ok too

```
y2=np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1])

xsimul=np.linspace(0,16,200).reshape(-1,1)
plt.plot(xsimul,y2)
```

[image]

But when I try to create the two plots together in one figure

```
plt.plot(xsimul,y2)
plt.scatter(df["x"],df["y"])
```

I got this plot

[image]

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data points in the dictionary are strings. These must be converted to integer before you make the plots. This could be done by making use of `astype()`. This results in the desired plot.

```
df["x"] = df["x"].astype(int)
df["y"] = df["y"].astype(int)
```

In this case the complete DataFrame could be converted to integers.

```
df = df.astype(int)
```